# Magento 2 : How to watermark pdf of a downloadable product?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, pdf, downloadable, watermark

Suppose a downloadable product has pdf uploaded as link and samples. How can i watermark that pdf in magento 2.1 with dynamic data like customer name . So , when user downloads it after order approval, he/she should get the watermarked pdf.

I have got customer name from session in `\Vendor\Module\Controller\Download\Link` which overrides `Magento\Downloadable\Controller\Download\Link` which is responsible for downloading the file.

Help me out peeps.